# How to use the background grid as a ruler for cutting objects in a straight line with the bisect tool?

Tags: edit-mode, workflow, bisect

Currently I have to use my eye to approximate a horizontal straight line for cutting an object with the bisect tool.

Is there a way to get the cursor to snap to a grid point (marked in red) so that the correct straight line is drawn?

[image]

I have used <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> but that doesn't do what I want.

Comment: After you've marked the cut with the Bisect tool, but before you click <RET> to finalise it, open the bottom-left settings dialog and set Plane Normal X dimension to zero.

Comment: @John Eason: It was right under my nose! Thanks

Comment: No problem! Easy to miss...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a plane, rotate it so it matches your perspective, and subdivide it so the quads match the big cells:

[image]

Then subdivide it again so it matches the small cells:

[image]

Of course you could subdivide it in a single step (39 cuts), but since a big cell always consists of 10 small cells and requires 9 cuts, it's easier to do in in two steps.

Now go to Object Mode, select both the plane and the object to be cut (here Suzanne), use knife snapping to the plane:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. This works too.